# How to include SeekBar in SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: android, seekbar, simplecursoradapter

I am using custom `SimpleCursorAdapter` to include a `SeekBar` in a `ListView`. But I can't seem to link the progress value to display in the `TextView`. Here is my sample code.

```
class TmpSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
        public TmpSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context _context, Cursor _cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(_context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item_temperature, parent, false);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context Context, final Cursor cursor) {
            //Room name, displaying in ListView Item
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBTemperature.COLUMN_TITLE));
            //Set temperature value, adjusting by SeekBar
            temperature = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.roomTemperature);
            SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {
                    temperature.setText("+" + progressValue);
                    Log.d(MEGA, "Progress Changed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    Log.d(MEGA, "Progress Started");
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    Log.d(MEGA, "Progress Stopped");
                }

            });

        }
    }
```

The logs even shows that it works properly, but values from the `SeekBar` are **not transmitting** to the `TextView`. Should I use `ViewBinder` for this? Or is there something missing in my code?

======================================================================

Next stage - using ViewBinder
I've changed the way to set ListView Rows, but there is still problem with SeekBar.

public class FragmentTemperatureDB extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks {

```
ListView lvTemperature;
DBTemperature dbHelperTmp;
SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapterTmp;
int LIST_TMP_ID = 0;

ActionMode tmpActionMode;
private int operatePosition = 0;
final static String MEGADOR = "megadr";

public FragmentTemperatureDB() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View vTemperatures = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_thermal, container, false);
    // Initialize data for ListView
    dbHelperTmp = new DBTemperature(FragmentTemperatureDB.this.getActivity());
    dbHelperTmp.open();
    String[] from = new String[] {  DBTemperature.COLUMN_TITLE,
                                    DBTemperature.COLUMN_CURRENT_TEMP,
                                    DBTemperature.COLUMN_ADJUST_TEMP};
    int[] to = new int[] {  R.id.roomTitleTmp,
                            R.id.roomTemperature,
                            R.id.adjustTemperature};
    // Setup Adapter for ListView
    dataAdapterTmp = new SimpleCursorAdapter(FragmentTemperatureDB.this.getActivity(),
            R.layout.row_item_temperature, null, from, to, LIST_TMP_ID);
    dataAdapterTmp.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(DBTemperature.COLUMN_ADJUST_TEMP)) {
                int adjustProgress = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
                ((TextView) view).setText("++" + adjustProgress);
                seekBar.setProgress(adjustProgress);
                seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {
                        //((TextView) view).setText("+" + progressValue);
                        Log.d(MEGADOR, "Progress Changed: " + "+" + progressValue);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        Log.d(MEGADOR, "Progress Started:");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        Log.d(MEGADOR, "Progress Stopped");
                    }
                });
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    lvTemperature = (ListView) vTemperatures.findViewById(R.id.temperatureListView);
    lvTemperature.setAdapter(dataAdapterTmp);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    lvTemperature.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
            operatePosition = pos;
            tmpActionMode = FragmentTemperatureDB.this.getActivity().startActionMode(new ActionBarCallBack());

            return true;
        }
    });
    // Make loader for getting data
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LIST_TMP_ID, null, this);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return vTemperatures;
}
```

SeekBar can't be initialized during process. Stacked why?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SeekBar.setProgress(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at com.gigavar.adkmegador01.FragmentTemperatureDB$1.setViewValue(FragmentTemperatureDB.java:69)
```

ROW 69 is `seekBar.setProgress(adjustProgress);`

Also if I uncomment row

```
//((TextView) view).setText("+" + progressValue);
```

view can't be accessed within inner class. And this is second problem.

Comment: You haven't added a view holder. Do that you and u will solve your problem.

Comment: why do you extend `SimpleCursorAdapter` overriding `newView` / `bindView` etc? if there are views that cannot be handled directly by `SCA` use a `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder `

Comment: Actually adding **view holder** nothing changed. As I know it needed for acceleration loading resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by getting needed TextView through Parent layout:

```
viewHolder.adjust = (TextView) ((View)seekBar.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.adjustTemperature);
                viewHolder.adjust.setText("+" + progressValue);
```

Also ViewHolder inserted

```
    static class ViewHolder {
    TextView roomTitleTmp;
    TextView adjust;
    TextView temperature;
    SeekBar seekBar;
}
```

Finally we have working SeekBar in every row with displaying progressValue

```
 class TmpSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    public TmpSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    }

    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    @Override
    public View newView(Context _context, Cursor _cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(_context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item_temperature, parent, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context Context, final Cursor cursor) {
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBTemperature.COLUMN_TITLE));
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.roomTitleTmp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.roomTitleTmp);
        viewHolder.roomTitleTmp.setText(title);
        viewHolder.temperature = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.roomTemperature);
        viewHolder.adjust = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adjustTemperature);
        viewHolder.seekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        viewHolder.adjust.setText("+" + viewHolder.seekBar.getProgress());
        viewHolder.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {
                viewHolder.adjust = (TextView) ((View)seekBar.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.adjustTemperature);
                viewHolder.adjust.setText("+" + progressValue);
                Log.d(MEGADOR, "Progress Changed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                Log.d(MEGADOR, "Progress Started");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                Log.d(MEGADOR, "Progress Stopped");
            }

        });

    }
}
```

[image]